# Как использовать array_merge

Tags: php

хочу получить

```
[
   ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
   ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
]
```

пробую так

```
foreach ($out as $key => $value)
{
    $tmp_arr = ['id'=>$key, 'name'=>$value];
    $result = array_merge($result, $tmp_arr);                    
}
```

но видать где то ошибся

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result=array();
foreach ($out as $key => $value)
{
    $result[] = ['id'=>$key, 'name'=>$value];
}
```